# What impact does deficit spending have on economic inequality?

Tags: macroeconomics, taxation, government-debt, inequality

Taxation schemes can be classified as progressive (the tax rate is higher for higher income brackets), regressive (the tax rate is lower for higher income brackets), or neutral (the tax rate is the same for all income brackets).

Conceptually, as compared to a neutral taxation scheme, a progressive one shifts the tax burden more towards the higher segments of the income distribution, and a regressive one shifts the tax burden more towards the lower segments.

Is there a way to reason about deficit spending in these terms? That is, which segments of the income distribution does the debt incurred by deficit spending burden more?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be discussed solely in terms of debt burden. It also matters what the (budget) money is used for. https://inequality.org/research/instead-budgets-ask-about-impact/

Comment: Your question has been asked (and answered) in reverse though: "Using cross-country
data we find evidence that a more unequal distribution of income can weigh on a
country's fiscal performance." https://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/publications/economic_paper/2010/pdf/ecp414_en.pdf